# display a child property in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

**Short:** How do I bind a DataGridColumn to a property of an object, but display a child property of the former one?

**Long:** I have a simple Class

```
public class Measurement
{
    public double xPosition { get; set; }
    public double yPosition { get; set; }
    public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is used by another class:

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set 
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private Measurement experimentResult;
    public Measurement ExperimentResult
    {
        get
        {
            return experimentResult;
        }
        set
        {
            experimentResult = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ExperimentResult"));
        }
}
```

I want to display a list of `Sample` in a DataGrid. In one column is the `Name` and the other column should show the `MeasuredValue` of the `ExperimentResult`. But I can't bind to `ExperimentResult.MeasuredValue` because that
doesn't throw the `PropertyChanged` event.

So the question is: How to show the `MeasuredValue` of the sample?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to stop you from binding to a property that doesn't raise a PropertyChanged event in it's setter - but your UI won't update when the property does. As far as binding to child properties, you can do so by turning off automatic column generation in the DataGrid, and then explicitly defining the columns you want.  In the process, you can reference child properties in the Binding statements:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ExperimentResult.MeasuredValue}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

For reference, this is my code behind:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Sample> _samples = new ObservableCollection<Sample>()
    {
        new Sample()
        {
            Name = "Sample1",
            ExperimentResult = new Measurement()
            { MeasuredValue = 100.00, xPosition = 1, yPosition = 0}
        },
        new Sample()
        {
            Name = "Sample2",
            ExperimentResult = new Measurement()
            {
                MeasuredValue = 50.00, xPosition = 2, yPosition = 3}
        }
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Sample> Samples
    {
        get
        {
            return _samples;
        }
    }
}

public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private Measurement experimentResult;
    public Measurement ExperimentResult
    {
        get
        {
            return experimentResult;
        }
        set
        {
            experimentResult = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ExperimentResult"));
        }
    }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public double xPosition { get; set; }
    public double yPosition { get; set; }
    public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
}
```